# Web based app for differential geometry visualization

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric, visualization, online-resources

Is there by any chance a web based app for viewing parametric curves and surfaces that arise in differential geometry to help visualization?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+equations)

Comment: Are these curves and surfaces already immersed in $\mathbb R^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about curves/surfaces that are [immersed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$. More abstract or higher dimensional curves/surfaces would be a bit harder to work with.

### Static Plots

As [HallaSurvivor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/655547/hallasurvivor) mentioned in a comment, [**Wolfram|Alpha**'s plotting and graphics capabilities](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20equations) include static plots of [parametric surfaces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d%20parametric%20plot%20%28cos%20u%2C%20sin%20u%20%2B%20cos%20v%2C%20sin%20v%29%2C%20u%3D0%20to%202pi%2C%20v%3D0%20to%202pi) and [curves](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d%20parametric%20plot%20%28cos%20t%2C%20sin%202t%2C%20sin%203t%29) in 3d, or [curves in 2d](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%28cos%5E3%20t%2C%20sin%5E3%20t%29).

### 2D Animations/Interactives

If you want something more interactive, [**Desmos**](https://www.desmos.com/)'s graphing [calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) works well for 2D. The [Desmos learn page on "parametric equations"](https://learn.desmos.com/parametric-equations) links to [an example page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ouobakqewe) including a *family* of parametric curves with an extra parameter $a$ that can be modified with a slider to display different curves. And [the Desmos learn page on "points"](https://learn.desmos.com/points) links to [an example page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkbrolohjs) including a parametric curve shown one point at a time where the parameter can be controlled with a slider. Pressing the play button ▶ will have the parameter increase at a fixed speed so the nature of the parametrization can be understood in motion.

### 3D Animations/Interactives

Finally, [the **Math3D app**](https://www.math3d.org/) has many features similar to Desmos, plus some additional features built in (e.g. vectors), and can handle interactive/animated parametrized curves and surfaces in 3D, as shown in the [Math3D example](https://www.math3d.org/ruled_hyperboloid) for a [ruled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) (of one sheet).

**Edit:** Thanks to [Semiclassical](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137524/semiclassical)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971602/web-based-app-for-differential-geometry-visualization/3971908#comment8193698_3971908) for reminding me about [the **GeoGebra 3d calculator**](https://www.geogebra.org/3d) which has similar functionality (and can do a lot more with some complicated inputs). Geogebra has [curve](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Curve_Command) and [surface](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Surface_Command) commands for parametric constructions. You can see both with some sliders in a [demonstration](https://www.geogebra.org/m/BjV7cNwb) by [matheagle](https://www.geogebra.org/u/matheagle). You can even code a [2d slider](https://www.geogebra.org/m/znvatyhp) to control a pair of parameters for a surface, as exemplified in [Lenore Horner](https://www.geogebra.org/u/lenore)'s [demonstration](https://www.geogebra.org/m/znvatyhp).

### Programming

I didn't mention this originally because there is a much steeper barrier to entry, but [**CoCalc**](https://cocalc.com/) has a free plan and could be used for graphing on the web if you're already comfortable with a relevant programming language. See [one collection](https://share.cocalc.com/share/69b1ad2d132c0d9c21e2fcdd6604d670e6182ee5/sage-3d-plots.ipynb?viewer=share) of examples (including a graph of a parametrized surface) using [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) and [one collection](https://share.cocalc.com/share/8b892baf91f98d0cf6172b872c8ad6694d0f7204/PythonDataScienceHandbook/notebooks/04.12-Three-Dimensional-Plotting.ipynb) (including a parametrized [triangulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)) using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) in [Python](https://www.python.org/).

Comment: Geogebra also has a 3D mode in addition to the more familiar 2D options.

Comment: Wow... thank you very much! I will explore these options.